# Entity Framework Core : The database transaction is not always rolled back on errors Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, veracode

An action item from the security scan is to address the following error

> The database transaction is not always rolled back on errors entity framework in DatabaseContext.cs

1. Open database connection with try {} block
2. Begin database transaction with try {} block
3. No unfinished transaction before closing database
4. Ensure the transaction is rolled back in the catch { } block or finally { } block

The method that causes this issue is

```
    public async Task CommitTransactionAsync(IDbContextTransaction transaction)
    {

        if (transaction == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(transaction));
        }

        try
        {
            await this.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch
        {
            this.RollbackTransaction();
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (this.currentTransaction != null)
            {
                this.currentTransaction.Dispose();
                this.currentTransaction = null;
            }
        }

    }
```

As far as I see, Catch block handles the roll back in case of any errors. Am I missing anything here?

**Update:**

Below is BeginTransaction method

```
    public async Task<IDbContextTransaction> BeginTransactionAsync()
    {
        if (this.currentTransaction != null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        this.currentTransaction = await this.Database.BeginTransactionAsync(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return this.currentTransaction;
    }
```

and it is used like

```
using (var transaction = await this.demoRepository.UnitOfWork.BeginTransactionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
                {
await this.demoRepository.UnitOfWork.CommitTransactionAsync(transaction).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
```

Comment: It's probably because the code uses some mixture of `transaction` parameter and `currentTransaction` field.

Comment: As currentTransaction is of type IDbContextTransaction, I guess, I don't have to call                 this.currentTransaction.Dispose(); separately, correct?

Comment: The point is that these are *2 separate* variables. From the code it is unknown what each of them is.  Your code commits `transaction`, but rollbacks/disposes `currentTransaction`. These might point to the same transaction object instance, but the code analyzer has no way to know that. You should use either one, but not the two. Also it is  unclear why you need `transaction` parameter if you have `currentTransaction` field set from somewhere else.